# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

Tags: java, struts

I am using My-eclipse and doing a struts project there is no syntax error but on starting tomcat server the following error appear in console.

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

and

javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Parsing error processing resource path jndi:/localhost/strutspro/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml

any idea whats the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Donwload [commons-logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/) and place the jar(s) in `WEB-INF/lib`.

And for the future - google the class name that is not found to see which library it belongs to, download it and put it on the classpath (`WEB-INF/lib` in this case)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've already found your solution, but my solution to the same problem was a little different.

Running Tomcat 4.1.29 inside Eclipse 3.6, I started receiving a very similar error (*Servlet /webcustom threw load() exception javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Parsing error processing resource path /WEB-INF/conf/struts-config-resource.xml,...*).

Neither performing an "Eclipse > Project > Clean", nor an "Eclipse > Servers > *(Tomcat Server Instance)* > Clean Tomcat Work Directory" would resolve the problem for me.

However, after a lot of trial and error, I found the solution to be this...

Eclipse > Servers > *(Tomcat Server Instance)*...

- Add and Remove > *(Remove resource from the Tomcat Server Instance)*
- Clean
- Add and Remove > *(Add resource back to the Tomcat Server Instance)*
- Publish
- Start

Hopefully this helps someone else.

-jpt